# Apply PanGesture to uiview in another class with action

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `ViewController iDragHomeViewController`

and another

`NSObject` class `iDrag`

**"iDragHomeViewController.m"**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *dragView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    [dragView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:dragView];

    iDrag *drag = [[iDrag alloc]init];
    [drag makeDraggableView:dragView];
}
```

**"iDrag.m"**

```
-(void)makeDraggableView: (UIView *)dragView {

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellPan:)];
    [dragView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer]; 

}

- (void)cellPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)iRecognizer {

   UIView *viewToDrag = [[UIView alloc]init];
   viewToDrag = iRecognizer.view;

   CGPoint translation = [iRecognizer translationInView:[viewToDrag superview]];
   viewToDrag.center = CGPointMake(iRecognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         iRecognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
   [iRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:[viewToDrag superview]];
}
```

Now what I am trying here is to make this "`dragView`"(belongs to `iDragHomeViewController`) draggable in `iDrag` class by applying it PanGesture.
But the code is crashing.

I know some people will suggest me to use `NSNotification` to handle Pan action in another class but I dont want to write a single line in `iDragHomeViewController` and handle everything in `iDrag` Class only.

Is it Possible ??

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure I need to know the error output but a guess...

From UIGestureRecognizer doc:

```
- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
target parameter:
An object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the receiver when it recognizes a gesture. nil is not a valid value.
```

Thats the reason why your app crashes. The drag object is already released while the recognizer tries to call the `cellPan:` method.

You initialize the iDrag object in `viewDidLoad` and is not retained. (It is not a member variable and not used anywhere else....). End of the `viewDidLoad` the iDrag object is released by ARC.

I would not make any other object responsible for handling pan gestures, unless I had a good reason for that. And would make the view controller responsible for creating gesture recognizer and handling the events.

I assume you have really good reason for that, like the handling is used by multiple views, etc... If it is the case then a better approach would be making iDrag object singleton(shared instance).

Comment: Hmm...understood, but making iDrag object singleton doesn't suit my scenario. 
Need some other approach.
Anyways thanks dude..!

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer solved / helped your problem, do not hesitate to mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

Just need to declare `iDrag` object as a property

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) iDrag *drag;
```